# Ajax does not allow alert to show up in asp.net with telerik

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik, popup, alert

I have an aspx page. On it I have a Telerik text box and a label along with many other controls. My requirement is if user types in a 0 or a number which does not exist in my SQL database then an alert should be shown. I mean if user types 0 and tabs alert saying "no zero allowed". If a number like 9393932 entered then check the SQL db and see that the number does not exist in my corresponding table and alert "no customer exists with that number".

```
<td><telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="rntbSearchCust" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" NumberFormat-GroupSeparator="" OnTextChanged="rntbSearchCust_TextChanged" Width="100px" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="0" /></td>
...
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblCust" runat="server" CssClass="alttabledata" />                                
    </td>
</tr>
...
<telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="rntbSearchCust">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="lblCust" />                                  
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy>
```

Also, if customer number exists then the label `lblCust` should show the customer name.

```
protected void rntbSearchCust_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rntbSearchCust.Value > 0)
    {...}
    else
    {
        string strError = "Please enter Cust number greater than 0.";           
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "show", "alert('" + strError + "');", true);
    }
}
```

I have debugged the program, it goes into the else part when I put in 0, but I never see the pop up. So I commented the ajax part and then I see the pop up. So, how should I show pop up with ajax still present? If you need more info, please ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use the RadAjaxManager to run the script like this :

```
else
{

RadAjaxManager1.ResponseScripts.Add("alert('Please enter Cust number greater than 0.');");

}
```

Pls give it a try! it should work.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to use the above line you suggested but it says an error "RadAjaxManager1 does not contain a definition for ResponseScripts and no extension method ResponseScripts accepting a first argument of type '' could be found". I have the using Telerik.Web.UI in my page.What is wrong?

Comment: replace your RadAjaxManagerProxy with RadAjaxManager

Comment: Well, I did that but got error saying only one instance of RadAjaxManager should exist. This page inherits from master page which already has RadAjaxManager. So i left the proxy as it is and did this:   RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(this).Alert("Please enter Cust number greater than 0."); It Worked!!!. Thanks